# Facebook Open Graph - LIKE is not displayed in the News Feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, haml

I have the LIKE button in the website, but URL like **https://www.website.com/something/1/something2/2** is not displayed in the News Feed on Facebook.

Here's my setup:

```
<html xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml' xmlns:og='http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/'>
 <meta content='New Listingggg' property='og:title'>
 <meta content='article' property='og:type'>
 <meta content='https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1234567890' property='og:image'>
 <meta content='https://website.herokuapp.com/something1/1/something2/2' property='og:url'>
 <meta content='Website name' property='og:site_name'>
 <meta content='New record' property='og:description'>
 <meta content='147949055123456' property='fb:app_id'>
 <link href='https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1234567890' rel='image_src'>
 <meta content='http://cache.thisorth.at/blog-images/00000/00000/161.jpg' name='image'>
 <link href='https://website.herokuapp.com/something1/1/something2/2' rel='canonical'>
 <meta content='en_US' property='og:locale'>
```

When I check this URL on the Facebook tool, I see there following:

**Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed** - *Bad Response Code:    URL returned a bad HTTP response code.*

**Errors That Must Be Fixed** - *Missing Required Property: The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.*

**Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed**

Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

I am fighting with this issue the second day and it drives me crazy, what am I missing?
The all tags that are mentioned that I am missing them are implemented in the website, thus... where could be the problem?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**
Updated HTML output.

**EDIT2:**
Output from console:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://website.herokuapp.com". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access. like.php?api_key=439601822731111&locale=cs_CZ&sdk=joey&channel_url=http%3A%…scheme=light&show_faces=false&send=false&extended_social_context=false:403
```

Comment: I'm not into Ruby on Rails but what is you output on the website (Page source)? And also the HTTP response code would be great if you could provide.

Comment: Hi `musse`, I updated the HTML output in the OP.

Comment: I can't really see any problems with your meta tags. Could you check you HTTP response code as well? This is a tool you could use for easy access: http://httpstatus.io/

Comment: It shows me: **STATUS CODE: 500** - `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. It Should be HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
Your problem is somewhere else. You have an internal server error as the message says. You should probably check you server logs.

Comment: But this has something to do with the javascript code?

Comment: No, this is a server error. Not client side. It is hard to know what it is if you don't get any errors or check your logs on the server.